# How to install libraries that require compilation on google-colaboratory

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

When trying to install a library that requires `cmake` like this:

```
!pip install dlib
```

the notebook returns the following error:

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cmake': 'cmake'
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `apt` commands on google-colaboratory, so you can easily install cmake:

```
!apt update
!apt install -y cmake
!pip install dlib
```